Traefik stops routing after some minutes (Docker Swarm)
Traefik stops routing after some minutes. (Docker Swarm)
I suspect it's when a service (any service) gets redeployed
I'm running 3 nodes in Docker Swarm
When I restart each server, the problem is fixed, until I redeploy the service or just wait a little time until one service get's redeployed automatically
It seems like no request reaches traefik. In traefik logs there's no logs when it comes to routing
It's really weird to me, because I can access Traefik dashboard, and every route is in there

Here's example WebApp (Dashy Homepage)
dashy-stack.yml:
version: "3.5"

services:
  dashy:
    image: lissy93/dashy:latest
    container_name: dashy
    networks:
      - web
      - dashy
    volumes:
      - /home/swarm/dashy/dashy-conf.yml:/app/user-data/conf.yml
      - /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/Warsaw
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.dashy.rule=Host(`dashy.home`)"
        - "traefik.http.services.dashy.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
        - "traefik.docker.network=web"
        - "io.portainer.accesscontrol.users=admin"
        - "traefik.http.routers.dashy.tls=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.dashy.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.docker.lbswarm=true" # Disables load-balancing in Traefik and delegates it to Docker Swarm. This still doesn't fix the problem


networks:
  dashy:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
    name: dashy
  web:
    external: true
    name: web


traefik-stack.yml
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:443"
    #  - "222:222"
    volumes:
      - "/home/swarm/traefik/traefik-conf.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml"
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - "/home/swarm/traefik/configuration/:/configuration/"
      - "/home/swarm/traefik/certs/:/certs/"
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Warsaw
    networks:
      - web

    deploy:
      labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.home`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=admin:$$apr1$$iB4qdp8O$$I2l4qaWhHUCWGyl7lkSEa/"
      # Dummy service for Swarm port detection. The port can be any valid integer value.
      - "traefik.http.services.dummy-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=9999"
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

networks:
  web:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
    name: web


traefik-conf.yml
### Static Configuration
http:
  middlewares:
    my-sablier: # For Sablier to Work
      plugin:
        sablier:
          group: non-essential
          dynamic:
            displayName: The service starts...
            refreshFrequency: 5s
            showDetails: "true"
            theme: ghost
          sablierUrl: https://sablier:10000
          sessionDuration: 1m

log:
  level: DEBUG
api:
  dashboard: true

serversTransport:
  insecureSkipVerify: true
  rootCAs:
    - /certs/rootCA.pem

certificatesResolvers:
  rootCAs:
    - /certs/rootCA.pem
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
  gitea-ssh:
    address: ":222"
  websecure:
    address: ":443"

providers:
  swarm:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
    network: web
  file:
    directory: /configuration/
    watch: true
# For Sablier to work:
experimental:
  plugins:
    sablier:
      moduleName: "github.com/acouvreur/sablier"
      version: "v1.6.1"

$  sestatus
SELinux status: disabled

Snippet of traefik logs:
guration/","watch":true},"providersThrottleDuration":"2s","swarm":{"defaultRule":"Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}`)","endpoint":"unix:///var/run/docker.sock","network":"web","refreshSeconds":"15s","watch":true}},"serversTransport":{"insecureSkipVerify":true,"maxIdleConnsPerHost":200,"rootCAs":["/certs/rootCA.pem"]},"tcpServersTransport":{"dialKeepAlive":"15s","dialTimeout":"30s"}}
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:25+02:00 INF github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/cmd/traefik/traefik.go:605 >
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | Stats collection is disabled.
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | Help us improve Traefik by turning this feature on :)
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | More details on: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/contributing/data-collection/
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    |
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:25+02:00 DBG github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/plugins/plugins.go:30 > Loading of plugin: sablier: github.com/acouvreur/sablier@v1.6.1
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:25+02:00 DBG github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp@v0.7.5/client.go:612 > Performing request method=GET url=https://plugins.traefik.io/public/download/github.com/acouvreur/sablier/v1.6.1
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:26+02:00 DBG github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp@v0.7.5/client.go:612 > Performing request method=GET url=https://plugins.traefik.io/public/validate/github.com/acouvreur/sablier/v1.6.1
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:27+02:00 INF github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/server/configurationwatcher.go:73 > Starting provider aggregator aggregator.ProviderAggregator
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:27+02:00 DBG github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/server/server_entrypoint_tcp.go:220 > Starting TCP Server entryPointName=gitea-ssh
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:27+02:00 DBG github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/server/server_entrypoint_tcp.go:220 > Starting TCP Server entryPointName=web
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:27+02:00 DBG github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/server/server_entrypoint_tcp.go:220 > Starting TCP Server entryPointName=websecure
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:27+02:00 INF github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/provider/aggregator/aggregator.go:202 > Starting provider *file.Provider
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:27+02:00 DBG github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/provider/aggregator/aggregator.go:203 > *file.Provider provider configuration config={"directory":"/configuration/","watch":true}
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:27+02:00 DBG github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/provider/file/file.go:122 > add watcher on: /configuration/
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:27+02:00 DBG github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/provider/file/file.go:122 > add watcher on: /configuration/certificates.yml
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:27+02:00 INF github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/provider/aggregator/aggregator.go:202 > Starting provider *traefik.Provider
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:27+02:00 DBG github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/provider/aggregator/aggregator.go:203 > *traefik.Provider provider configuration config={}
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:27+02:00 INF github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/provider/aggregator/aggregator.go:202 > Starting provider *acme.ChallengeTLSALPN
traefik-swarm_reverse-proxy.0.tlnifr2qp9c9@swarm3    | 2024-05-20T20:14:27+02:00 DBG github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/provider/aggregator/aggregator.go:203 > *acme.ChallengeTLSALPN provider configuration config={}


$ curl -vk https://dashy.home
* Host dashy.home:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 192.168.1.140
*   Trying 192.168.1.140:443...
* Connected to dashy.home (192.168.1.140) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 / x25519 / RSASSA-PSS
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: O=mkcert development certificate; OU=cloufish@carbs
*  start date: May 17 17:35:34 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 17 17:35:34 2026 GMT
*  issuer: O=mkcert development CA; OU=cloufish@carbs; CN=mkcert cloufish@carbs
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
*   Certificate level 0: Public key type RSA (2048/112 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* using HTTP/2
* [HTTP/2] [1] OPENED stream for https://dashy.home/
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:method: GET]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:scheme: https]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:authority: dashy.home]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:path: /]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [user-agent: curl/8.7.1]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [accept: */*]
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: dashy.home
> User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Request completely sent off


